# Safari View Controller customizing size, frame add as a subview

Tags: ios9, sfsafariviewcontroller

How can I customize Safari View Controller to have my navigation bar and my navigation bar button to be seeing on the screen? Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess as Apple suggest that there is only a way to use WKWebView if we need some custom appearance, custom size.